# Using returned variables in other functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return

I am pretty new to python, and I was wondering about `return` and the stuff inside `()` when defining a new function. I **do not** want to run any code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`. I want a function to do it. Why won't this work?

```
def money():
    coins = 100
    return coins
def doubleMoney(coins):
    doubleCoins = int(coins * 2)
    return doubleCoins
def printMoney(doubleCoins):
    print("Your coins doubled are:", doubleCoins) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    money()
    doubleMoney(coins)
    printMoney(doubleCoins)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "work"?  It won't do anything because you never call any of the functions.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just fixed it.

Comment: You need something more like `printMoney(doubleMoney(money()))`.

Comment: If you have more than one question please start a new thread instead of changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that will not work.  Think of a function as a machine.  You put things in one end (arguments, aka "the stuff in `()` when defining a new function), and you get something out at the other end.  What you get out is a *value*.  It doesn't create a variable with a certain name or anything like that.

So if you want to use the value of `doubleMoney(coins)`, you have to do something with it.  In your example, you just call `doubleMoney(coins)`.  This will result in a value, but you don't do anything with it.  If you want one function to use a value that another function returns, you have to link them up somehow.  What you probably are looking for is something like:

```
coins = money()
doubleCoins = doubleMoney(coins)
printMoney(doubleCoins)
```

You could also do it all in one line with `printMoney(doubleMoney(money()))`.

They key thing is that just because you did `return coins` doesn't mean a variable with that *name* is created when `money()` returns.  Only the *value* is returned; if you want to make a variable, you have to do that yourself outside the function, like in the example I showed.

Comment: I want to run it without actually defining anything when it executes. I want the function to do that.

Comment: @retep: You can do that by creating global variables, but that is unrelated to returning values, and is also not a good idea.  Or you can do what I said in my second one-line example.

Comment: I made a program with global variables, and I am trying to remove them. That's the problem. See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117070/python-blackjack-program

Comment: I just needed to open a new question.

Comment: @retep: The answer to your question there suggests the same thing I suggest here (`bet = get_bet(tokens)`).  Getting rid of global variables is a good idea, but you need to abandon the idea that you can just take your existing code and somehow "remove the global variables" while leaving everything else the same.  Often, if your code is relying on a lot of global variables, improving it will involve restructuring it in a fairly deep way.  (That's one reason you want to avoid using global variables in the first place, to avoid having this pain later.)

Comment: Great, thanks! What if I wanted to define say, more than one thing in a function? Like `coins` and `credits` in `money()`, and use them later?